# How to add an ajax throbber to my theme?

Tags: 9

I created a new theme based on Classy.

```
base theme: classy
core_version_requirement: ^8 || ^9

regions:
  header: 'Header'
  content: 'Content'
  footer: 'Footer'

libraries-extend: {}

libraries:
  - my_theme/global
```

```
global:
  version: VERSION
  header: TRUE
  js:
    dist/js/app.js: { minified: true }
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/drupal
    - core/ajax
    - core/drupalSettings
    - core/jquery.once
  css:
    theme:
      dist/css/app.css: { minified: true }
```

No matter what I do - I don't get AJAX loading indication in my views or when infinite scroll loads. What am I missing?

What do I define in Drupal to show or use my own throbbing markup?
Can't google this thing at all.

If I need to handle this myself in a new there is there any resources where I can read how to create a custom ajax throbber?

Comment: This question is unanswerable because you did not include all of the relevant code. All that is there as I write this comment is library definitions, absent their file names. Also, please limit this to one question only. There are two questions here: "How to add a ajax throbbler to my theme? Or how to write a new one?"

Comment: @cilefen what do files name has to do with throbbers? I am asking what libraries I need to get it to work in a new theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to insert some js logic **before** and **after** a Drupal Ajax request.

```
Drupal.Ajax.prototype.ajax_before_send_original = Drupal.Ajax.prototype.beforeSend;

Drupal.Ajax.prototype.beforeSend = function (xmlhttprequest, options) {
  Drupal.Ajax.prototype.ajax_before_send_original.call(this, xmlhttprequest, options);
  options.complete_original = options.complete;
  options.complete = Drupal.Ajax.prototype.options_complete;

  // BEFORE AJAX LOGIC
  // e.g. jQuery('.listing-ajax-overlay').addClass('active');
}

Drupal.Ajax.prototype.options_complete = function (xmlhttprequest, status) {
  this.complete_original.call(this, xmlhttprequest, status);

  // AFTER AJAX LOGIC
  // e.g. jQuery('.listing-ajax-overlay').removeClass('active');
}
```